# AutoMapper Map and Flatten Entity with List

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following data model

```
public class Products
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }
}

public class ProductSize
{
    public double UnitSize { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductPackage> ProductPackages { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPackage
{
    public int ItemsPerPack { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProductPrice> ProductPrices { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPrice
{
    public double Price{ get; set; }
}
```

And I want to map it to the following Dto

```
public class ProductDto
{
    public name Name{ get; set; }
    public double UnitSize { get; set; }
    public int ItemsPerPack { get; set; }
    public double Price{ get; set; }
}
```

I have read into using AutoMapper for this, but am unsure how to setup the configuration because there would be 4 sources mapping to one destination, all from lists. I would expect to there to be multiple items with the same property values and that is desired. Do I have to ForMember<> map for each item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in a [Custom Type Converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters):

```
Func<Products, IEnumerable<ProductDto>> conversion = product => 
    from size in product.ProductSizes
    from package in size.ProductPackages
    from price in package.ProductPrices
    select new ProductDto {
        Name = product.Name,
        UnitSize = size.UnitSize,
        ItemsPerPack = package.ItemsPerPack,
        Price = price.Price
    };

Mapper.Initialize(c => c.CreateMap<Products, IEnumerable<ProductDto>>()
                        .ConvertUsing(conversion));  


var product = GetProduct(…);
var dtos = Mapper.Map<Products, IEnumerable<ProductDto>>(product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Stuartd's answer is great. But now I am thinking why even rely on AutoMapper at this point. We can just do this:

```
public class Products {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public ICollection<ProductSize> ProductSizes { get; set; }

   public IList<ProductDto> ConvertTo() {
      var q = from size in ProductSizes
      from package in size.ProductPackages
      from price in package.ProductPrices
      select new ProductDto
      {
         Name = this.Name,
         UnitSize = size.UnitSize,
         ItemsPerPack = package.ItemsPerPack,
         Price = price.Price
      };

      return q.ToList();
   }
}
```

I ran this as a test and without AutoMapper it takes .0000768 and with AutoMapper it takes .0836274:

```
class Program {
static void Main(string[] args) {
   var c = new ProductPackage
   {
      ProductPrices = new List<ProductPrice> { new ProductPrice() }
   };
   var p = Enumerable.Range( 1, 100000 ).Select(x =>
   new Products
   {
      Name = "Good Product",
      ProductSizes = new List<ProductSize> {
      new ProductSize { Name = "Small", UnitSize = 10, ProductPackages = new List<ProductPackage> { c } } }
   } ).ToList();

   Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
   w.Start();
   var dto = p.Select(x => x.ConvertTo());
   Console.WriteLine("Without AutoMapper it took: {0}", w.Elapsed);
   w.Stop();

   DoWithAutoMapper(p);

   Console.Read();
}

private static void DoWithAutoMapper(List<Products> p) {

   Func<Products, IEnumerable<ProductDto>> conversion = product =>
         from size in product.ProductSizes
         from package in size.ProductPackages
         from price in package.ProductPrices
         select new ProductDto
         {
            Name = product.Name,
            UnitSize = size.UnitSize,
            ItemsPerPack = package.ItemsPerPack,
            Price = price.Price
         };

   Mapper.Initialize( c => c.CreateMap<Products, IEnumerable<ProductDto>>()
                              .ConvertUsing( conversion ) );

   Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch();
   w.Start();
   var products = p;
   foreach( var item in p ) {

      var dtos = Mapper.Map<Products, IEnumerable<ProductDto>>( item );
   }
   Console.WriteLine( "Using AutoMapper it took: {0}", w.Elapsed );
   w.Stop();
}
```

The only downside I see is the coupling of Products to ProductDto. I am not sure if this should be a comment. I guess it is another approach.

Comment: I don't think this is the answer: if I understand the question correctly OP wants to map an instance of `Products` into a list of `ProductDto` objects. Also, you don't need to add `ForMember` calls when the source and destination names are the same, that's why it's **Auto**mapper.

Comment: @stuartd you are correct, I want a list of ProductDto from one product (because there are many sizes, packages and prices)

Comment: @stuartd can you please see the edit because your answer inspired that. Actually most of it is your answer.